# python M2Crypto HMAC SHA1

Tags: python, openssl, hmac

I have to create a HMAC_SHA1 hash in the way of:

```
auth_reponse = HMAC_SHA1(key=session_id, data=decypted_challenge)
```

How can i do this with M2Crypto ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
from M2Crypto.EVP import HMAC
import base64

hmac = HMAC(session_id,'sha1')
hmac.update(decypted_challenge)

auth_response = base64.encodestring(hmac.digest()) #Base64 format
```

or:

```
auth_response = hmac.digest() #Binary format
```

Regards!